# Service posting straight to Azure Queue

Tags: api, azure, post, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I have this service that posts JSON messagest to a given url, the requests cannot be modified and because of that I cannot add all the headers I need to post to a queue in Azure.

I have been researching on this but seems like the only way to make a post other from the authorization headers is allowing a range of IPs to post to the Q; something that I cannot do either because the sender can change IPs and I could loose data, not good.

What I'm trying to find out is if Microsoft has a way (or some different service from queues) that I can use to prevent data loss in case my app is down (this is where the queue comes in), or if there's some way I can allow this external provider to post to my queue without all the security or with a minimum of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Can you please describe it in more details.

Comment: @GauravMantri it's pretty simple, I have an external system posting to a url that inserts those records in the db. I want to add a queue service in the middle of these two. I've been reading and the best for my scenario might be a Service Bus Queue but still trying to figure out how to post without being inside an application, maybe using Postman for example.

Comment: If you're using Storage Queues, then you can post a message directly in a queue by creating a shared access signature for that queue and using SAS URL in the external system. You would however still need an application that would dequeue the messages from that queue, parse the messages and then insert records in a database.